# How to filter json data from Google's Places API using the "types" keyword with python

Tags: python, google-places-api

I have pulled json data from Google's Places API using Python. I have gotten to the point of being able to extract the name and phone number for each establishment. I can do this for the types of businesses supported in the API ("car_repair" for example. I want to be able to pull more specific types than "car_repair" ("auto_body_shop" for example). When I run the below code it will pull that names and phone numbers of the first 20 results from the API within the specified radius. The problem is that none of them are auto body shops.

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_KEY)
places_result = gmaps.places_nearby(location= "40.35003,-111.95206", radius= 4000000,open_now= False,type= 'car_repair')
pprint.pprint(places_result)
for place in places_result['results']:
    my_place_id = place['place_id']
    my_fields = ['name','formatted_phone_number','type']
    place_details = gmaps.place(place_id = my_place_id, fields = my_fields)
    print(place_details['result']['name'],place_details['result']['formatted_phone_number'])
```

Any ideas would be helpful to expand the types of businesses I can pull from the API. Another possibility that comes to mind is pulling a broader category of businesses than "car_repair" and filtering the json data to extract only the types I want...